Azure functions Timer Trigger Unscheduled invocation
I have a Timer trigger in my functions app. The trigger is executed with little delay and creates unscheduled invocation error and continue to execute multiple times. Due to this, I could see multiple outputs after the execution. Though I don't see successful execution in logs. I could see the results at the backend. I'm using EP1 plan.
 Executing 'Functions.TimerTrigger' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-08-30T00:04:10.6629861+00:00'

Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule: 2024-08-30T00:00:00.0000000+00:00

Executing 'Functions.TimerTrigger' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-08-30T00:07:15.7262110+00:00',

Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule: 2024-08-30T00:00:00.0000000+00:00

Executing 'Functions.TimerTrigger' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-08-30T00:15:19.5976211+00:00'

Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule: 2024-08-30T00:00:00.0000000+00:00
 



[Function("TimerTrigger")]
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%Cron%")] TimerInfo timerInfo)
{
       await methodAsync();
}

    


Can you share your code in the question?

@DasariKamali I have added the snippet. I don't think issue is with the code. It is working in my test environment. But issue occurs in production. Log Analytics is enabled for the functions. Surprisingly, I don't see the log in requests table. Only traces has these.

I tried the below sample Timer trigger function, which worked both locally and in production.
Code  :
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp5
{
    public class TimerTriggerFunction
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public TimerTriggerFunction(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TimerTriggerFunction>();
        }

        [Function("TimerTrigger")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%Cron%")] TimerInfo timerInfo)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            if (timerInfo.ScheduleStatus is not null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {timerInfo.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
            }

            await MethodAsync();
        }

        private async Task MethodAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000); 
            _logger.LogInformation("MethodAsync completed.");
        }
    }
}

Program.cs :
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule toRemove = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

            if (toRemove is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(toRemove);
            }
        });
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddApplicationInsights(console =>
        {
            console.IncludeScopes = true;
        });
        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    })
    .Build();
host.Run();

local.settings.json :
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage_conneString>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "Cron": "0 */5 * * * *" 
  }
}

Local Output :

I deployed the Timer Trigger function to the Azure Function App and updated the following setting under App settings in Environment variables as shown below.
Cron : 0 */5 * * * *


Azure Function app Invocations :


I have a working setup in test environment. Question is how do I resolve when the issue occurs in prod. I'm not sure how to reproduce, I do see this issue raised by multiple customers, but no concrete solution
